# How to move files in sftp server?

Tags: rename, sftp

How can I move a file in sftp server on a different directory? I connect to this server using sftp and then try to move a file using

```
mv myfile.csv /my/dir/myfile.csv
```

but this generates an error. How to to do this?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91544/move-a-remote-file-at-an-ftp-prompt

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There is no `mv` command in the interactive mode of sftp. Use `rename` instead.

To learn which commands are available, check the man page `man sftp` or type `help` within `sftp`.

Comment: sftp's `rename` works just like `mv` in the shell!

Comment: @Devy except for wildcards, and omitting the filename if moving into a dir!

Answer (score 2):

The client `lftp` can be used for both FTP and SFTP. It has a `mv` command you can use to perform a move on the remote server. There's a good tutorial on using it here, titled: [Unix: Flexibly moving files with lftp](http://www.itworld.com/operating-systems/371170/unix-flexibly-moving-files-lftp).

If you look through the `lftp` usage you'll notice a `mv` command.

```
$ lftp
lftp :~> help
    !<shell-command>                     (commands)                           alias [<name> [<value>]]             attach [PID]
    bookmark [SUBCMD]                    cache [SUBCMD]                       cat [-b] <files>                     cd <rdir>
    chmod [OPTS] mode file...            close [-a]                           [re]cls [opts] [path/][pattern]      debug [<level>|off] [-o <file>]
    du [options] <dirs>                  exit [<code>|bg]                     get [OPTS] <rfile> [-o <lfile>]      glob [OPTS] <cmd> <args>             help [<cmd>]
    history -w file|-r file|-c|-l [cnt]  jobs [-v]                            kill all|<job_no>                    lcd <ldir>
    lftp [OPTS] <site>                   ln [-s] <file1> <file2>              ls [<args>]                          mget [OPTS] <files>
    mirror [OPTS] [remote [local]]       mkdir [-p] <dirs>                    module name [args]                   more <files>
    mput [OPTS] <files>                  mrm <files>                          mv <file1> <file2>                   [re]nlist [<args>]
    open [OPTS] <site>                   pget [OPTS] <rfile> [-o <lfile>]     put [OPTS] <lfile> [-o <rfile>]      pwd [-p]
    queue [OPTS] [<cmd>]                 quote <cmd>                          repeat [OPTS] [delay] [command]      rm [-r] [-f] <files>
    rmdir [-f] <dirs>                    scache [<session_no>]                set [OPT] [<var> [<val>]]            site <site-cmd>                      source <file>
    torrent [-O <dir>] <file|URL>...     user <user|URL> [<pass>]             wait [<jobno>]                       zcat <files>                         zmore <files>
```

#### References

- [Move a remote file at an FTP prompt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91544/move-a-remote-file-at-an-ftp-prompt/91559#91559)